# How prevent Google Tagmanager from changing javascript values?

Tags: javascript, decode, equals, encode, google-tag-manager

This is the Custom Html Tag that is in Google Tagmanager:

```
<script>
 _dAutomationGtmAddTimer("mysite.com", "bh2Ry58My0NWFw==", {"cmp1": 
 visitorContactInfo[0], "cmp2": visitorContactInfo[1], "cart_data":[{"amount":orderFormProducts[quantity],"id":orderFormProducts[sku],"image":"","link":"URL produto","name":orderFormProducts[name],"description":"","unitary_value":orderFormProducts[sellingPrice]}]})
</script>
```

The second parameter `"bh2Ry58My0NWFw=="`, when injected to the DOM by Tagmanger changes to `"bh2Ry58My0NWFw\x3d\x3d"`, replacing `==` with `\x3d\x3d`.

Please, any idea how to prevent this value from changing?

Comment: Please read on [ask].

Comment: For what it's worth, it's URI escaping the equals symbol so it can be sent in a URL. I don't know right off hand how to fix it in tag manager though.

Comment: Is `bh2Ry58My0NWFw==` a fixed value? Or does it vary from call to call?

Comment: @vinoaj yes, it's a fixed value

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

**First**, create a Constant Variable:

- Variable name: API key
- Variable value: `bh2Ry58My0NWFw==`

**Then**, modify your Custom HTML tag to look like

```
<script>
 _dAutomationGtmAddTimer("mysite.com", "{{API key}}", {"cmp1": 
 visitorContactInfo[0], "cmp2": visitorContactInfo[1], "cart_data":[{"amount":orderFormProducts[quantity],"id":orderFormProducts[sku],"image":"","link":"URL produto","name":orderFormProducts[name],"description":"","unitary_value":orderFormProducts[sellingPrice]}]})
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @vinoaj .  It didn't work. I'm working with a e-commerce platform called Vtex, and i'm thinking this might be some security script that's encoding special characters. I'll get in touch with their support team. Thank you very much!